# Constructing clear url from a array

Tags: php, arrays, youtube, preg-replace

I have a array which has almost 150 values like

```
    { [0]=> string(670)
    "https://r3---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com/vide.......................xpire=1407349366&mws=yes" [1]=> string(36) "type=video/mp4; codecs="avc1.640028"" [2]=> string(10)
    "init=0-712" [3]=> string(8) "itag=137" [4]=> string(15) "bitrate=4138626" [5]=> string(9) "=713-1080" [6]=> string(20) "lmt=1407180456062432" [7]=> string(28) "clen=52223505,size=1920x1080" .............}
```

and so on. Above I have used var_dum to show the array length. There are almost 10 urls in the array and all url has a length of 500 character or more. So I don't need all the array  values except the string length 500 or more. I think I can use if and for loop to echo all the urls but I have failed to put it together.

After taking the url arrays there is another problem. In the url array sometimes it might contain at the first like

```
"url=https://r3---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com....."
```

and at the end like

```
"url=https://r3---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com.....xpire=1407349366&mws=yes,itag=137"
```

I want to remove all the characters before https and after the "," including it. I want to echo plain url.

If possible I want to take it a bit step further. In the array there is another which has a length of 8 character. Actually I want to take the itag value.

```
[3]=> string(8) "itag=137"
```

But string length is always not same sometimes like

```
[3]=> string(12) "type=mp4,itag=137"
```

And the itag value will always change like "itag=136".

Finally I want a result like this

```
    136 => https://r3---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv.......
    137 => https://r2---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv.......
    22 => https://r4---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv.......
    37 => https://r7---sn-oguesnl6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&mv.......
    .......................................
```

So is that possible if not I want to pick only the url. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

```
preg_match("(var ytplayer(.*)ytplayer.config.loaded)", $downloaded_page, $match);
$link = $match[1];
$adaptive_fmts = preg_match("(adaptive_fmts(.*)})", $link, $adaptive);
$stream_map = preg_match("(url_encoded_fmt_stream_map(.*)})", $link, $stream);
$adaptive_link = urldecode($adaptive[1]);
$stream_link = urldecode($stream[1]);
preg_match("(url=(.*)\\\\)", $adaptive_link, $final);
$search_array = array('u0026','u0026index','u0026clen','index','u0026size','u0026init','u0026lmt','u0026url=','u0026bitrate','u0026type');
$trimmed = str_replace($search_array, '', $final[1]);
$one = explode('\\' , $trimmed);
var_dump($one);
```

Comment: How are you generating the array in the 1st place? Thats probably where you should focus your attension

Comment: may be you are right ... i have already used explode and paese_str function...from tehm I think it will be easier...if you are willing to see how i have created the array i can show you@user574632

Comment: Sure, show how you are creating the array and i will take a look

Comment: please take a look at the update section @user574632

Comment: what does $downloaded look like? is it html? please show what it looks like so i can help your parse it

Comment: Yes, I am downloading the entire html page. $downloaded_page = curlGet("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8zj57YG4GE");  @user574632

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58797/discussion-between-user2978381-and-user574632).